# OpenCV Python: drawMatchesKnn() function

Tags: python, opencv

I tried using the function `drawMatchesKnn()` in python with the `opencv-2.4.10.exe`, but I am receiving the error message:

`'module' object has no attribute 'drawMatchesKnn'`.

So I built `OpenCV 3.0.0` from source with `CMake` and now I am getting the error message:

`'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'`

How can I use both functions `SIFT()` and `drawMatchesKnn()`?
The code I am trying to run is from the Opencv tutorials: http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

Answer (score 0):

SIFT and SURF were moved to https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/ in opencv3.0.

you will have to download that repo, add it to your main opencv cmake settings(take your time with the readme there), and rerun cmake / make / make install.

then, invoke it like:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() # note the additional namespace !
```